# Draggable and Droppable dynamic postioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to build a puzzle using jQuery UI. I have got parts of the puzzle, #splinter and a container #vase to posision it:

```
<div id="vase">
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
<div class="splinter splinter-1" data-target-x="53" data-target-y="90">
    <img src="splinter-1.png" />
</div>
```

I use the data attributes of the parts to set the position of the droppable. this works, but the snaparea is not being recalculated. The parts stil snap to the area where it was originally positioned.

```
$('.splinter').draggable({
revert: 'invalid',
snap: '#target',
snapMode: 'inner',
start: function (event, ui){
    var $target = $('#target');
    $('#vase').append($target);
    $this = $(this);
    $('#target').droppable('destroy').droppable({
        accept: '.splinter'
    });
    $target.css({
        width: $this.width(),
        height: $this.height(),
        left: parseInt($this.attr('data-target-x')),
        top: parseInt($this.attr('data-target-y'))
    });
    $this.draggable('option', 'snap', '#target');
},
stop: function (event, ui){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.draggable('destroy');
}
});
```

**EDIT:**

I found out that if I drag an element and release it again then an drag it to the snapping div, it works. Of course i have to disable the revert option for that. Has anyone expirienced this behaviour before?

Thanks

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use refreshPositions:true. It's horrible on performance though, so you likely want to set and reset it each time you drop/move.

```
$('.splinter').draggable({refreshPositions:true,...});
```

Another gotcha, I'm guessing you're going to have a lot of puzzle pieces at some point. jQuery drag/drop doesn't handle this so well. You might want to look into some of the plugins which will allow you to use event delegation with drag/drop.

You may be able to do this better by setting position on click (or some other event):

```
$('.splinter').click(function(){...set css position...}).draggable(...);
```

This would fix any problem where the position have been calculated before "start" is called, which is where you change position of the target droppable.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the positions aren't being recalculated. You may be doing something that jquery ui draggable and droppable glitch up on. Possibly set you position before drag? To be honest, I only briefly looked into using draggable/droppable before I found too many issues to use it for my purposes.

Comment: If this answered your question mark it as such, and if you're feeling nice you can vote up too :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in which order the callback functions are executed. The "start" callback function gets called after the snap elemnts positions are calculated. I repositioned the #target div in this callback. This is how I solved this issue:

```
$('.splinter').mousedown(function(){
    var $target = $('#target');
    //$('#vase').append($target);
    $this = $(this);
    $target.css({
        width: $this.width(),
        height: $this.height(),
        marginLeft: parseInt($this.attr('data-target-x')),
        marginTop: parseInt($this.attr('data-target-y'))
    });
});
```

Instead of the callback function I bind for the mousedown event which is being triggered before the click event which draggable uses.